# организация работы телеграм бота через webhook

Tags: python, ubuntu, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу бот на вебхуках первый раз. При запуске через консоль на сервере (`sudo python3 main.py`) бот НЕ работает, если добавить `sudo` запускается и работает.

Подскажите каким образом его можно запустить используя `/etc/systemd/system/bot.service файл` (раньше писал боты с использованием `bot.polling(none_stop=True`), так как по идее `bot.service` не админ и не может работать через порт *возможно в этом я не прав*).

Порт для хуков использую `80`, (8443 не получается, хотя он открыт).

Возможно есть другой вариант для запуска постоянной работы бота на сервере.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую Google Cloud Platform с ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы запустить ваш скрипт как сервис, вам нужно выполнить эти команды:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable bot.service
sudo systemctl start bot.service
```

Первая - перезагрузит демон systemctl для того, чтобы он просканировал папку с файлами .service заново, вторая - включить автозапуск при старте системы, третья - запустит сервис немедленно.

Сервис будет работать от root, поэтому описанных проблем с запуском быть не должно.